What's the name of this movie about an African American doctor?
This is an American movie.  I don't think it's very old, maybe 90's at the latest but most likely 2000's.  There is an African American who is either an intern or a student, I want to say it's at a college.  He is mentored by a European American professor or doctor, and encouraged to become a doctor himself.  I think it's based on a true story, and I want to say the African American doctor becomes the first African American to perform open heart surgery or something.  I remember the African American is played by a rapper, and I want to say the European American is a famous actor but I can't remember who he is or what else he was in.
Does this movie sound familiar to anyone?  I saw it on HBO a few years back so it may have been an HBO production and not released in theaters.

Could be the HBO movie Something the Lord Made from 2004 with Alan Rickman and Mos Def about heart surgery pioneers Alfred Blalock and Vivien Thomas. From IMDb:

Alfred Blalock (1899-1964), a cardiologist (therefore, self-confident to the point of arrogance), leaves Vanderbilt for Johns Hopkins taking with him his lab technician, Vivien Thomas (1910-1985). Thomas, an African-American without a college degree, is a gifted mechanic and tool-maker with hands splendidly adept at surgery. In 1941, Blalock and Thomas take on the challenge of blue babies and invent bypass surgery. After trials on dogs, their first patient is baby Eileen, sure to die without the surgery. In defiance of custom and Jim Crow, Blalock brings Thomas into the surgery to advise him, but when Life Magazine and kudos come, Thomas is excluded.

The entire movie is currently available on Youtube here.
